# Custom sounds for local notification in iphone is not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Im integrating local notification into my app.

It is working fine.

But client want to use a different sound for local notification.

I drag and drop the file into the supporting files of xcode

Can anyone please help me how to do this.

```
code
AlocalNotifas.soundName = @"cling.wav";
    localNotifas.soundName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"cling" ofType:@".wav"];
   //  [localNotifas setSoundName:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"cling" ofType:@"wav"]];
   //  [localNotifas setSoundName:UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName];
```

Can you experts please show me where im going wrong.

Comment: I can have this same issue.  Have tried all suggested answers, converting audio file, deleting app, clean cache, etc.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Remember that your notification sounds may not be longer than 30 seconds - if the file supplied is longer, nothing will sound.

Also, check the sound in some external player first, and best convert it to .caf format.

To convert a file to .caf, open up terminal, go to where you have your sound stored and type in:

```
afconvert -f caff -d LEI16@44100 -c 1 yourfile.wav yourfile.caf
```

Then just set it like:

```
yourNotification.soundName = @"yoursound_name.caf";
```

Comment: can you please help how to create a settings bundle for iphone

Comment: sure, but I don't know what you mean by settings bundle.

Comment: when i googled some are saying that we have to integrate to apps bundle.(i assume that it is just to drag and drop into the xcode.)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8042/discussion-between-user923370-and-peter-sarnowski)

Comment: Wow, this was very helpful! I tried 2 different sound file formats but they both didn't work. Then I changed the format to caf as you suggested, and it worked like magic! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use your local notification object and set its soundName property to sound file

```
[localNotif setSoundName:@"abc.mp3"];
```

Answer (score -4):

Be sure to copy the sound file in the root of the project.

you can also use the name of the sound directly, by example...

```
localNotif.soundName = @"marimba.mp3";
```